Laravel Wave sample project - no SSE messages between Laravel Development Server and client
Try to create sample Laravel 11 project to test SSE with Laravel Wave:
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-sse
cd laravel-sse
composer require qruto/laravel-wave
npm install --save-dev laravel-echo laravel-wave sweetalert2
npm run build

Then create event:
php artisan make:event RealTimeNotification

Change event source app\Events\RealTimeNotification.php to:
class RealTimeNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(
        public string $message
    )
    {
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('events'),
        ];
    }
}

Modify routes (web.php) to:
// Bad: Route::view('/wave', 'welcome');
Route::view('real-time-notifications', 'sse');

I don't know why these parameters are the following - I got them from Laravel SSE Sample
Then add JavaScript subscriber in resources/js/bootstrap.js:
import { WaveConnector } from 'laravel-wave';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: WaveConnector,
});

window.Echo.channel('events')
    .listen('RealTimeNotification', (e) => {
        console.log('e', e)
        Swal.fire({
            position: 'top',
            icon: 'success',
            title: e.message,
            showConfirmButton: false,
        });
    });

Start Laravel as php artisan serve.
What I've seen at Laravel Development Server console - /wave message indefinitely. Guess it's ok.
Then try to push event in tinker as event(new \App\Events\RealTimeNotification("Hello World!")); - no visible reaction at browser console.
What I've seen at browser console - nothing. No errors, no valuable data.
What's wrong?

If there is 500 (Internal Server Error) in console, there should be logs  in storage/logs directory, which should have detailed info about the error and the stack trace. Please include any errors you find there

Yes, there were problems with Redis. So, for now with proper Redis configuration error 500 disappeared. But anyway client don't receive any sse message

Is your queue setup correctly and running? Did you run php artisan queue:work ?

If the error 500 is resolved, and thereby unrelated to the issue, please update your question to excluded the unrelated data
